# Using CSS styling hooks on lighting datatable rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, slds, datatable, slds-styling-hooks

I want to increase the height of the rows in the lighting (I also want to change the spacing and add shadows)According to the documentation [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#Styling-Hooks-Naming-Conventions). But I cant seem to target the row element of the datatable. These are the hooks I've tried so far:

```
:host{
    --slds-c-datatable-row-height : 200%;
    --slds-c-datatable-tr-height: 200%;
    --slds-c-datatable-tr-lineheight: 200%;
    --slds-c-datatable-row-lineheight: 200%;
    --slds-c-datatable-row-line-height: 200%;
    --slds-c-datatable-tr-line-height: 200%;
    --slds-c-datatable-row-line-height-line-height: 200%;
    --slds-c-datatable-tr-line-height-line-height: 200%;
}
```

Is there something wrong in the hooks I'm trying or is it just not possible to modify the CSS of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those custom properties are not defined in SLDS. Indeed the documentation page you linked states:

> For the most up-to-date information on available component styling hooks, please visit the [Blueprint Overview](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/overview/) page and select your desired component

So you should always check the blueprints to know which styling hooks are available.
Unfortunately, according to [Data Tables Blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/), there are no styling hooks available for that component, so you cannot modify the CSS of the rows due to [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom), but you can use that blueprint to build your own component and apply every style you want.